# Uploading an image in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am new in Zend Framework and learning it. I want to upload image into my database and display that image in view page. I search lots of tutorial but no step by step guidance. Want a help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take a look on `Zend_Form_Element_File` in [Zend documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html):

> The File form element provides a mechanism for supplying file upload
>   fields to your form. It utilizes Zend_File_Transfer internally to
>   provide this functionality, and the FormFile view helper as also the
>   File decorator to display the form element. By default, it uses the
>   Http transfer adapter, which introspects the $_FILES array and allows
>   you to attach validators and filters. Validators and filters attached
>   to the form element are in turn attached to the transfer adapter.

Database side, you need to use a [BLOB type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) to hold your image (I assume you're using MySQL).

However, note that best practices are **to store the image path in the database** instead of the image itself.
At last, there are tons of tutorials out there that explains precisely how to do what you're looking for, you just need to look for "file upload using zend element file" and you will find  them!